# How to pass array of images to detailView Swift?

Tags: arrays, image, swift

Well I have been making a test app to continue my swift learning, today I came across a problem.
Basically I have a tableview and a detailview. For my tableview file I have some data that I am currently passing to the detailview, like the name that goes on the navigation bar, one image and some text,  this data is stored in arrays on my tableview file, I use "prepareforsegue" to pass this information:

```
var names = ["name1","name2","name3"]
detailViewController.detailName = names[indexPath.row]
```

Then in my detailViewController I have variables set for that:

```
var detailName: String?
```

Then I use this for stuff, example: naming my navigation bar or setting an image in detailView:

```
navigationItem.title = detailName!
```

Now, what I dont get how to do is pass a whole array of information to a variable in my detailViewController. What I want to do is pass an array of images to use it on my detailView. I want to be able to iterate through the array of images with a button, I know how to set that up but I just need to know how to pass the array, right now I am just passing one of the values(one name, one image etc...)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so different from what you have done.

Just add field for images in `detailViewController`, and then pass images using it. Images could be represented in `[UIImage]`.  However, `[String]` can be also used for local filenames, and `[NSURL]` can be used for remote image urls.

code:

In `DetailViewController`:

```
var images: [UIImage]? // or var images: [UIImage] = []
```

In `prepareForSegue`:

```
detailViewController.images = YourImages
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for one of two things:

- A UIImage array, which you can declare using `var imageArray : [UIImage] = []` and then append whatever images you want to pass.

Alternatively, you can pass in a [AnyObject] array and cast its elements to a UIImage or String by doing

```
var objectArray : [AnyObject] = []
objectArray.append("test")
objectArray.append(UIImage(named: "test.png")!)

if let s = objectArray[0] as? String {
  // Do something with the string
}
if let i = objectArray[1] as? UIImage {
  // Do something with the image
}
if let s = objectArray[1] as? String {
  // The above cast fails, this code block won't be executed
} else {
  // ... but this one will
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the table view controller file:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
    var detailImages: Array<UIImage> = []
    detailImages.append(UIImage(named: "pup.png")!)
    detailImages.append(UIImage(named: "cutepuppy.png")!)
    detailVC.detailImages = detailImages;
}
```

and in the detail file:

```
    var detailImages: Array<UIImage>?
```